# simplexmlelement array to <xml file format

Tags: php, xml

let say my code below is a xml object code

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[data] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[delivery_info] => SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
 [carriage_list] => SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
  [carriage] => SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
[name] => aa
[price] => 0.00
 )
 )
```

now need convert it to example below

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
<data>
<delivery_info>
<carriage_list>
<carriage>
<name>aa</name>
<price>aa</price>
</carriage>
</carriage_list>
</delivery_info>
</data>
</document>
XML;
```

so how i do it? i got search many time already ,no any answer to me
pls help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asXML($filename)` function of `SimpleXMLElement` or cast type to `string` if you don't need to save to file:

```
$xml = (string) $element;
```

Comment: hi can reply this ques too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062647/how-to-use-curl-get-simplexmlelement-and-echo-them  thanks